# BASH/AppleScript Self Replicate File

Tags: bash, applescript, replication

I'm trying to make an update program that can self replicate across a network using BASH or AppleScript. It must be a one line command if it's done in BASH and SSH keys aren't an option as I don't have direct access to every computer. I guess this is kind of like a worm or something? I have the admin username and passwords for all the computers. Does anyone have a method for this? The computers don't have file sharing turned on either.

In short, I need to replicate with no user interaction.

Comment: If what you were suggesting were possible, wouldn't it be a glaring hole in security?

Comment: @Jeff Bowman I wouldn't think it would be a security hole due to the fact that you would still need a username and password for authentication. I'm well aware that you can't just take 2 computers and tell them to do stuff without privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just copying it to all machines and then executing it there is an option, try `sshpass` which lets you "pipe" a password to an ssh/scp password prompt as well as further commands to the machine onto which you are sshing. Take a look [here(for scp)](https://serverfault.com/questions/318474/how-to-pass-password-to-scp-command-used-in-bash-script) and [here (for passing commands)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282319/how-to-use-sshpass). Now all you need is that ugly file from which you read user names and passwords - the security issue with this file is obvious, I guess ... I am aware that this would not be self-replicating, but hopefully fulfil your task to update the whole network.

Comment: That should be able to work. I can open an `nc` listening port with the `sshpass` and then send the file. Only problem is that i would have to install `sshpass`, but I might also be able to package it into my AppleScript. Thanks.